# Creating a customized "Open-With" dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

When I click on a file , multiple  options appear in the "Open With " dialog . This is because I send an intent with Action_VIEW and there are multiple Apps to receive it.

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + location);
```

For security reasons , I want to disable some of them ,  for example , a printer App to be used to open files from my App.

Is there a mechanism to filter out the options or choose which ones to show ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with SetPackage if you know the application name. For example, in your code, you can specify the package name using setPackage

```
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setPackage("com.test.print");
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse("file://" + location);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question since it could benefit anyone looking for something similar .
So , this is how you can customize and create your own Open With Dialog :

Step 1 : Get a list of Apps which you want to display . For that you need to screen out the Apps from the intent .

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mimeType); 


List<ResolveInfo> getAllAppswhichcanViewtheFile =   (List<ResolveInfo>)getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    Iterator<ResolveInfo> i = getAllAppswhichcanViewtheFile .iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ResolveInfo file = i.next();

    // Use condition to filter the List 
        if (file.activityInfo.packageName.contains(XXXX)) {  
            i.next(); 
        } else {          
            i.remove();
        }

      List<ResolveInfo> resolvedPrintList = getAllAppswhichcanViewtheFile ;
```

Step 2 : Display the Filtered Apps on a Alert Dialog :

```
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle(DataUtils.getString(R.string.xyz));
        final OpenWithArrayList adapter = new OpenWithArrayList(this,           R.layout.basiclistview, R.id.text1, resolvedPrintList);
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                ResolveInfo info = (ResolveInfo)adapter.getItem(which);
```

intent1.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName,info.activityInfo.name);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                }
            });

```
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
```

Step 3 : Creating the adapter : 
public class OpenWithArrayList extends ArrayAdapter{

```
    Context context;
    Object[] items;
    boolean[] arrows;
    int layoutId;





public OpenWithArrayList(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<ResolveInfo> objects) {


    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = objects.toArray();
        this.layoutId = resource;

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     View row = convertView;

     if(row==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.basiclistview,parent, false);
      TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text1);
     label.setText(((ResolveInfo)items[position]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());
     ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.logo);
     image.setImageDrawable(((ResolveInfo)items[position]).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));

     }


     return(row);

}
```

}